# String to dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a string to dictionary. Example:

```
Milk, Cheese, Bottle
```

The program will convert it to dictionary.

```
{"Milk":"NULL", "Cheese":"NULL", "Bottle":"NULL"}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> string = 'Milk, Cheese, Bottle'
>>> dict((key, None) for key in string.split(', '))
{'Cheese': None, 'Milk': None, 'Bottle': None}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> s = "Milk, Cheese, Bottle"
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(s.split(', '),"NULL")
>>> d
{'Cheese': 'NULL', 'Milk': 'NULL', 'Bottle': 'NULL'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dict.fromkeys((k.strip() for k in "Milk, Cheese, Bottle".split(',')), 'NULL')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'Milk, Cheese'
d = { }
for s in s.split(', '):
    d[s] = 'NULL'
```

You can also use dictionary comprehensions in the latest Python versions:

```
s = 'Milk, Cheese'
d =  {key:'NULL' for key in s.split(', ')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> from collections import defaultdict:
 >>> s = "Milk, Cheese, Bottle"
 >>> j = s.split(',')
 >>> d = defaultdict()
 >>> for k in j:
     d[k]= 'NULL'
 >>> dict(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same solution as Zaur Nasibov's, but using list comprehension to run the for loop in fewer lines

```
s = "Milk, Cheese, Bottle"
d = dict((i, None) for i in [i.strip() for i in s.split(',')])

>>> print d
{'Cheese': None, 'Milk': None, 'Bottle': None}
```

Hope this helps