# Convert string from external file to Python dictionary

Tags: string, python-2.7, dictionary

I've looked around but I haven't really found a solution. I have external TXT file that contains strings separated by commas, each "item" is on new line:

```
item1: value1
item2: value2
```

etc. you get the idea.

I am creating script that works with dictionary and I need to convert the file to Python dictionary. I'm still a newbie so I'm kinda lost.

I have tried this which I found here [String to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937629/string-to-dictionary) :

> dict((key, None) for key in string.split(': '))

But I am unable to figure out how to replace 'None' with sth that represents Value of a Key. I did try dict((key, value)) but 'value' is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```
dict((key, value) for key, value in [string.split(': ')])
```

Note that this will fail if there are multiple `': '`'s in the string.

This peace of code works like the following:

```
>>> string = 'hello: world'
>>> string.split(': ')
['hello', 'world']
>>> a, b = string.split(': ')
>>> a
'hello'
>>> b
'world'
```

The values will be strings this way. If they should be for example integers, use `(key, int(value))`. This, also, is not failsafe if there are none-integer values.

Remark: As of Python 2.7, which you tagged your question with, you can use dictionary comprehensions. This is a bit cleaner:

```
{key: value for key, value in [string.split(': ')]}
```

This will, however, get you a lot of dictionaries of size 1. I think you'll need something like this:

```
{key: value for line in fileobject.readlines() for key, value in [line.split(': ')]}
```

You could also use the split directly:

```
dict(tuple(string.split(': ')) for string in fileobject.readlines())
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. Thanks to your advice I have finished my first program/miniscript. You see I'm not a programmer so I'm totally stoked on that (you can check it out here: https://github.com/ondrejsynacek/flashCardStudy)

Comment: Anyway I used Python 2.7 so most of that stuff you posted didn't work but this one did:

`{key: value for line in fileobject.readlines() for key, value in [line.split(': ')]}`

I am still trying to wrap my head around it. I still don't get how Python recognizes variable _line_ since it's not declared anywhere. I believe this has to do with .readlines() function.

I guess I need to do much more research on _for_ and string module, and dictionaries too.

Comment: The `line` variable is assigned in the for loop. Python doesn't really declare variables, they magically jump into existance.

Answer (score 0):

I asked around on #Python (FreeNode) to help me with this as well and there seems to be more "neat" solution.

> fileobject = open('text.txt', 'r')
>
> fdict = {}
>
> for line in fileobject.readlines():
>
> > for key, value in [line.split(':')]:
> >
> > > fdict[key] = value

This seems more clean to me and more understandable.